# Cheaper alternative to VS Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

Is there a fairly inexpensive source control product on the market that integrates into Visual Studio 2008+ and that has the power and capabilities of Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server?

I have used Dynamsoft, SourceGear, Subversion and Platic SCM and reckon that neither of these products can come close to Team Foundation Server.

Ideally I would be interested in a product that:

1. handles conflict resolution well
2. handles IDE edits, renames and deletes automatically
3. easy project management within the source control "server" that allows a project administrator to painlessly manipulate the project structure as they see fit.

Comment: What features in particular are you looking for?

Comment: Team Foundation is a big product that does many things. Perhaps if you gave us your requirements we can point you in the direction of other products that do one thing well and that integrate with each other.

Comment: Concerning features, 1) conflict resolution, 2) proper and well handled IDE edits, renames and deletes 3) project management within the source control "server"

Comment: By project management what do you mean? You should also edit this information back into your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subversion with Tortoise SVN

Here is an [article by Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/subversion/#Subversion_and_Visual_Studio) on setting everything up.

I used svn at my last job, and tfs at my current one.  I can't say I really like having to deal with tfs on a day to day basis.

Comment: He said Subversion doesn't come close.

Comment: I think it was because he didn't have it integrated into visual studio.  Though I could be wrong.  I really havn't come across anything that tfs does that svn with tortoise svn doesn't do more cleanly.

Comment: why would you use anything other than this combo? it baffles me.

Comment: @ Matthew You must be referring only to source control.  TFS does much, much more than source control.

Comment: This is true. I am referring only to source control, and source control eventing.

Comment: There are free and/or open source project management suites that integrate with svn.  Several are wonderful alternatives to tfs project management features.

Answer (score 4):

SubVersion and [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) will integrate directly into Visual Studio.

Comment: While AnkhSVN is free, it was rather slow on larger projects. I haven't used it in a while so maybe they improved performance, but for me it was reason to switch to VisualSVN.

Answer (score 4):

[Visual SVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/) is a tool to integrate SVN directly with Visual Studio.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [visualsvn.com](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/screenshot.png))</sub>

It costs $49 per license.

They have a [demo](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/demo/) so you can see if it what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I can't see why this add-in wouldn't have everything you might want.

Comment: I prefer to manage source control outside of the IDE so TortiseSVN is where it is at for me.

Comment: AnkhSVN is a Free Subversion SourceControl Provider for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Try [visualsvn](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/).

**EDIT**

Use VisualSvn as server (my bad, should have clarified I meant that), and as for the client, I used AnkhSVN, which got quite good over time.

Comment: Which costs 49$ for a single license.

Comment: Server is free (and quite nice btw), the client is not.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I've recently started using Team Foundation at work. Some of it is nice, but our team has spent at least 10 hours in total last week to fix silly TFS problems that never should have occurred in the first place.

While it isn't perfect, I find Subversion superior in many ways when it comes to plain source control. Get [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and shell out 50 bucks for [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) if you want an integrated solution.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I much prefer SourceGear Vault to SVN.

But it's hard to argue with free, and Vault is pretty expensive if you have more than 2 users.

Answer (score 2):

From what I hear, [VisualHg](http://sharesource.org/project/visualhg/wiki/) is a good Visual Studio addin for the [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/) distributed source-control system. You just need to [install TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/downloads/TortoiseHg-0.8-hg-1.3.exe) and then [VisualHg](http://dl.sharesource.org/visualhg/visualhg-1.0.6.msi), and you'll be up and running.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use SVN in conjunction with bug tracking solutions such as [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). There is a [Trac Visual Studio plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vstrac/files/). There is also [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), though I don't know about its VS plugins.

If all you do is to "view, compare, attach changesets to work items and annotate", I guess bug tracking solutions are quite good.

Answer (score 0):

What features of Team Foundation in particular are you interested in?

If you're just interested in Source Code Control, there are many plugins available for various other products.  Subversion for instance has several plugins available which give a very similar experience to the Team Foundation plugin.  AnkSVN is my personal favorite.

- http://help.collab.net/topic/com.collabnet.anksvn.doc/concepts/ankh_whatis.html

Comment: I really enjoy the way developers can easily view, compare, attach changesets to work items and annotate. Using some of the other version control system have not really ... inspired me as TFS has.

Answer (score 0):

We're going with Git but it probably doesn't have the integration with VS2008 you'd want.

Git manual: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html

Answer (score 0):

Mike,

If you are just looking for source control, the answer is yes.

If you are looking for an inexpensive replacement for everything that TFS does (build, test, project management, etc.) the answer is *heck, no.*